# Knockout js: Viewmodel property not being bound for dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

This is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aaScC/8/

Please check in the example, the Score property has 3 value but it is not being displayed . I know the score property is bound to dropdown value so its coming.

But I want 3.00 to be displayed.

```
var GoalsModel = function (goals) {
   var self = this;
   self.goals = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(goals, function (goal) { 
       return new Goal(goal) 
   }));
};
```

Comment: When I look at the fiddle I see 2 goals with 3.00 displayed. Could you be more specific about what you actually want? Thanks for the fiddle though.

Comment: @scaryman Please check the row with text "Goal1-1-1" which does not have rating. I want that row to have rating. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

you data has this line

```
        "GoalTitle": "Goal1-1-1",
        "GoalDescription": "",
        "HasSubgoals": false,
        "Score": 3
```

and your template has this line

```
  <span data-bind="text: Score, visible: Hassubgoals">
```

If you want the score to display always just remove the visible binding.

```
  <span data-bind="text: Score">
```